# xsl variables resulting in an empty document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to build an xsl style sheet to translate some abbreviated values into longer (human readable) ones.

I'm using xsl 1.0 and testing in notepad++ using the xml tools plugin

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assets>
    <asset>
        <asset.asset_id>7c69a3f9-bf2e-45b9-9bb2-9125d2967612</asset.asset_id>
        <ContentType>GA</ContentType>
        <RightsHolder>ITS</RightsHolder>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <Competition>SA</Competition>

        <GameDate>20180105</GameDate>
        <HomeTeam>FIO</HomeTeam>
        <AwayTeam>INT</AwayTeam>
        <VideoResolution>SI</VideoResolution>
        <DynamicRange>S2</DynamicRange>
    </asset>
    </assets>
```

and my stylesheet looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="assets" />

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="contenttypeshortcode">
<xsl:value-of select="assets/asset/ContentType" />
</xsl:variable>

etc
```

But with more variables selecting the various other elements. With the variables included in the document, Notepad++ says The transformation has generated empty document

If I remove the variables, I just get an untransformed copy of the input (as expected).

I had gone further than just creating the variables and started to produce output but when I hit this error I started removing code from the transform until I no longer got the error.

I'm not sure what it is about the variables that is resulting in an empty transform, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you define the variables outside of the templates. What are you going to do with these variables?

Comment: Are you sure the definition of the variable **contenttypeshortcode** is correct? I would have selected "/assets/asset/ContentType". Mind the first "/"

Comment: I've tried changing the xpath as suggested but that doesn't affect the results.

the variables are going to be used later in the transform, inside a template eg:

<xsl:template match="assets/asset">
<assets>
<asset>
<ContentTypeShortCode><xsl:value-of select="$contenttypeshortcode" /></ContentTypeShortCode>
 <ContentType><xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$contenttypeshortcode = 'GA'">Soccer</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$contenttypeshortcode = 'TA'">Soccer</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</ContentType>

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1xU You are probably using a non-conforming processor. -- P.S. Please do not post code in comments.

Comment: Thanks and thanks Michael. I will test with the link you have provided instead and noted on not posting code in comments in future